# Xcode 14 Beta - Unable to change current date text color in UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uikit, ios16, xcode14

In my application I have customised a UIDatePicker (set custom color for selected date) that was working correctly in iOS 15.5 and lower versions but when I run the app in iOS 16 beta, I don't see my settings for current date is working. Check the following code currently Im using,

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.calendar = .current
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
     datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}

datePicker.setValue(UIColor.systemPink, forKeyPath: "textColor")
datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

Please find the screenshot for more information and kindly share your feedback if any. Thanks in advance.
[image: Customised UIDatePicker from Xcode14 beta 4 (14A5284g)]

Answer (score 2):

The `highlightsToday` key is no longer working in iOS 16. The best approach will be removing the `highlightsToday` and `textColor` keys and change the appearance by setting only [preferredDatePickerStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/3526124-preferreddatepickerstyle).

Alternately, you can use `datePicker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` or `datePicker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light` to achieve black and white colors.